# How can I wrap a mousemove jQuery event in a conditional?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm exploring some different ways of filtering bot traffic from my site. Unfortunately, since many of these more sophisticated bots can execute JavaScript, many of my old tricks to exclude bot traffic from Google Analytics no longer work.

One idea I had is to use jQuery to only fire a pageview when a mousemove is detected on the document, like this:

```
var counter = 0;
if(counter === 0){
          $(document).mousemove(function(event){
               alert("Fire an event to GA here");
               counter += 1;  
          }
     );
}
```

This does indeed fire the alert when the mouse is moved, but unfortunately the alert continues to pop up even though it has already fired once. My other concern is that I'd like to disable the event handler once it has fired, since mousemove can be resource intensive to the user.

Is this possible? And is there a better way to do this besides mousemove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of the counter is broken, but there's no need to keep the `mousemove` event handler attached to the document after it's fired. Try using [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind the event so that it will execute only once:

```
$(document).one("mousemove", function(event){
    alert("Fire an event to GA here");
});
```

Comment: This require it be bound with `.on()`, no?

Comment: @SetSailMedia I tested it and it works with `$(document).mousemove` but `$(document).one` is an even better solution.

Comment: Thanks for clarify, I thought `.off()` was for use only with `.on()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('mousemove', function(){
    alert("GA triggered");
    $(document).off('mousemove');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're darn close. You just inverted your if() by placing it outside the binding.

Look at jQuery's [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) as well.

```
var counter = 0;
$(document).mousemove(function(event){
      if(counter === 0){
           alert("Fire an event to GA here");
           counter += 1;  
           $(document).unbind( "mousemove" );
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use one ([jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/one/))

So this will look something like this for your code:

```
$(document).one('mousemove',function(){
alert("Fire an event to GA here");
       counter += 1;  
});
```